# Is it possible to tell whether the user set an option using docopt?

Tags: python, docopt

Consider the following simple program.

```
from docopt import docopt

doc = """
Usage: ./opt.py [options]

    -h,--help         show this
    -a <option>       generic option [default: Foo]
"""

options = docopt(doc)
print options['-a']
print options
```

Is it possible to differentiate in my program between the following two user invocations?

```
python Opt.py -a Foo
python Opt.py
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't differentiate if you define a default value. But you could remove the default value from the docstring and set it programmatically.

```
from docopt import docopt

doc = """
Usage: ./opt.py [options]

    -h,--help         show this
    -a <option>       generic option
"""

options = docopt(doc)
if options['-a']:
    # option was defined
    ...
else:
    # option was not defined
    options['-a'] = "Foo"
    ...
```

But anyhow, for which use-case would that ever be necessary at all?